# NetSuite CSV Import for Transaction (Cash Sale)

Tags: netsuite

I have a .csv which contains some data of cash sales which i need to import in NetSuite, in Cash Sale Record there is Items sub list which I need to add 2 Items for each record but i can only add 1 item at a time because for Item it doesnt show the + mark like any other sublist to add more then 1 item [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h12OC.png)

is there any other ways to solve this issue other then manually updating each field in NetSuite and adding another Item

Comment: For single file CSV import it should have one line per item. Just repeat the the values not related to the item on each row. For multi-file import you can have the items in a separate file.

Comment: Figuring out the two file import process will save your sanity.  The header file and the line item file must share a key column. That column doesn't have to be actually imported (i.e. it doesn't have to have to be mapped to a Netsuite field) although if you are importing from an external system (eCommerce?) then the external system's order Id is a natural key that you'd likely want to map to something in Netsuite as a reference